# UWP cannot sideload on Win10

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to sideload a small UWP (Visual Studio 2017, target version 16299) on a Win10 Pro (1709) machine. When packaging in release mode I get the error “entry point not found”. Several programmers report the same recently, and in all those discussions there is no clear solution and some say it was a bug (somewhere) in Windows. (What puzzles me is, that there are so few who have this problem when there must be 100,000 programmers out there who need to upload their apps to the Windows Store…) Tried to step down to lower target versions, but these do not recognize the MySQL database to which the app must connect. The “compile with NET.Native tool chain” must be unchecked anyway, otherwise debugging ends with an “native error”.

It is a private project, so I could live with packaging in debug mode. This works for the developer machine, but the app does not install on the target machine. It says that the “…CoreRuntime 2.1 package” is missing, although in the dependencies folder there is a “CoreRuntime 2.1.appx”. Is it not what is needed? (package / appx?) Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

Comment: "100,000 programmers out there who need to upload their apps to the Windows Store" - hahahahahah. No.

Comment: It seems your app can not run on the release mode, do you use some NuGets in your project? Could you provide a simple repro sample? By the way you can install the CoreRuntime 2.1.appx manually.

Comment: Yes, MySQL Data is installed. Can this prevent from running on release mode? Regarding CoreRuntime: Can there be more than sitting in the dependencies folder? Or do you mean I should install the CoreRuntime on the target machine separately? Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: @Dai: if you know something substantial - speak out. Otherwise...

Comment: Yes, you can try to install the CoreRuntime on the target machine separately. And I also try to create a package using the MySQL Data, the app should set target and min version to 16299. it works well in my side whatever is in release or sideloading.